# В стандартной библиотеке database/sql нет возможности работать с событиями, как это обойти без cgo?

Tags: golang, события, firebird, уведомления

Я использую [драйвер firebird](https://github.com/nakagami/firebirdsql).

Появилась необходимость отслеживания событий в таблицах (insert, update).
С удивлением обнаружил, что в выше упомянутом драйвере нет поддержки нотификации событий.

В репозитории есть issue [на эту тему](https://github.com/nakagami/firebirdsql/issues/34).

Автор отвечает что в стандартной библиотеке database/sql нет возможности работать с events.

Вопрос в следующем:
Каким образом я могу поработать с нотификациями событий?

Возможно есть более низкоуровневый способ не прибегая к cgo.

Comment: Самое тупое и простое- это сделать отдельную таблицу, повесить триггеры на интересующие таблицы и заставить в эту одну таблицу писать, а затем из программы ее с некоторой периодичностью опрашивать.

Answer (score 2):

Для таблицы добавить поле `LAST_DATE`

```
CREATE OR ALTER TRIGGER TABLE_T1 FOR TABLE
ACTIVE BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE POSITION 0
AS
begin
New.LAST_DATE = 'NOW';
end
```

так получаем дату обновления записи, триггеры можно создать более сложные, для примера записать старые данные которые будут удалены или обновлены в отдельную таблицу.

```
CREATE OR ALTER TRIGGER TABLE_T2 FOR TABLE
ACTIVE AFTER UPDATE OR DELETE POSITION 0
AS
BEGIN
INSERT INTO HISTORY_TABLE (data1,data2,data3,data4)
VALUES (OLD.data1,OLD.data2,OLD.data3,OLD.data4);
END
```

Не забываем про триггер на таблицу HISTORY_TABLE, что бы понимать, когда произошло то или иное действие.

```
CREATE OR ALTER TRIGGER HISTORY_TABLE_T1 FOR HISTORY_TABLE
ACTIVE BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE POSITION 0
AS
begin
New.LAST_DATE = 'NOW';
end
```

И так далее, собирая историю в отдельные таблицы позволяет следить за данными и в случае случайных удалений/обновлений поможет получению обновленных данных, не прибегая к восстановлению БД из бекапа.

Есть конечно ряд минусов - увеличение объема хранимых данных, увеличение времени стандартных операций при записи, удалении, обновлении данных, особенно ощутимо при пакетных операциях.

UPD:

Так же триггером можно отправлять события:

```
CREATE TRIGGER POST_NEW_ORDER FOR SALES
ACTIVE AFTER INSERT POSITION 0
AS
BEGIN
POST_EVENT 'new_order';
END^
```

Где new_order - название события.

Comment: Вопрос был в том как я могу поработать с нотификациями, а не про то как это можно реализовать иначе.

Comment: @ЕвгенийГусев http://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/fblangref25-en/html/fblangref25-psql-coding.html#fblangref25-psql-tbl-postevent

Comment: UDP - читаем внимательно вопрос и понимаем в чем проблема.

Comment: @Gopher, https://github.com/nakagami/firebirdsql/pull/92